# Rails delete dependent records in custom delete method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

At the moment I am trying to run a "soft_delete" method that I made when a user deletes their account. Instead of completely deleting the user from the database it overwrites their username and email. However, I do want the method to delete all the posts that the user has made.

I've been trying multiple different ways. This is the controller at the moment.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts, :dependent => :delete_all

   #Method to soft delete and overwrite Username and Email for accounts
      def soft_delete
      Post.where(:user_id => user.id).delete_all
      update_attribute(:name, "DeletedUser")
      update_attribute(:email, "DeletedUserEmail#{id}")
      update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.current)
    end
   end
```

But now I get the error:

```
  undefined local variable or method `user' for #<User:0x00007fc9a42d48d8> Did you mean? User! User?
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa "I do want the method to delete all the posts that the user has made.".

Comment: @Ismael Barkat Have you tried the gem `paranoia` instead of using your way of soft-deleting a user?

Comment: from where you will get `user_id`?

Comment: I find it quite hilarious how there's been a recent flurry of "soft delete/anonymisation" posts in the past week, as thousands of companies suddenly realised GDPR is a real thing ;)

Comment: I'd suggest Paranioa gem for this... you could create a callback that overwrited username as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says "undefined local variable `user`". It should also tell you which line the error originates from (which you didn't share here), but it's presumably this line:

```
Post.where(:user_id => user.id).delete_all
```

There is no `user` method defined in the `User` class. You're only trying to get the `id` of `self` - i.e. you can just write:

```
Post.where(:user_id => id).delete_all
```

However, this is not necessary either. Since each user `has_many :posts`, you can just write:

```
posts.delete_all
```

Comment: Yeah you were right it was from that line. And thanks a lot I had overlooked that it was trying to get itself... Bit of a careless mistake there.

I changed it to just 
    posts.delete_all 

and it worked